# Is there a windows program to automatically indent/tidy up PHP source code?

Tags: php, windows

Is there a windows program to automatically indent/tidy up PHP source code?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PHP_Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier). The package contains a .bat so you can run it from your dosprompt.

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) has a "Code Format" feature (Ctrl+Shift+F)

Note: This has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367591/is-there-a-code-style-enforcer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785287/are-there-any-free-cmd-line-scripts-which-can-re-format-php-source-code)

Answer (score 1):

This type of tool is generically called a "Pretty Printer". A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+pretty+printer) shows many options for PHP source code.